# Sharepoint 2010 enterprise search error: "scope in your query does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 and enterprise search: I programmatically created a new custom search scope "MyScope", verified that it exists in search service app, issued full crawl. I created search page and search result page on which I assigned the new scope to search results web part. When I issue a query I get the following error: "scope in your query does not exist".